# Masking credit cards PAN with zeros

Tags: pci-dss

The PCI-DSS only requires you to protect the PAN if you are storing **more than** the first six and last four digits. Can an all zero masks be used?  E.g. 4111 1100 0000 1234 to make it PCI compliant / not sensitve.

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem with it from a compliance perspective. The traditional way is to use asterisks (*) or hashes (#) to block out the digits, but zeros should be fine too. The point is that you're meant to not display (i.e. hide) the real digits.

My only concern is that it could be confusing to a user that looked at the number, as it's ambiguous (from one data point) as to whether the card number legitimately had a zero as it's 7th or 12th digit, or whether that's just the mask. This isn't a compliance problem; it's just a case of a user potentially misunderstanding the use of zeroes.

Comment: I would say that using zeros could be a compliance issue, since there is the chance that the first 6 + 0's + last 4 could make a valid card number. if that were the case you would be in violation of PCI requirements.

Comment: @Timee That makes no sense at all; it's like saying having a database of every number from 0000 to 9999 violates PCI because you're guaranteed to have someone's PIN in there.

Comment: @Polynomial When an auditor does a scan of your systems and finds you're storing full card numbers, that will open up unnecessary discussions at the least. I think what Timee is trying to say is that if your masking function produces real card numbers, in a very small number of cases the input card equals the output card. That seems like a bad masking function at least and a non-compliant one at worst.